# Player doesn't move and timer doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame

My player doesn't move and my timer doesn't count down like it should. I'll post my whole code, so you can recreate everything I have. The timer stuff is inside the main_loop_state_config right after the for loop.

```
import pygame, os
from pygame.locals import *
import random


###############################################################
# Color-Codes
###############################################################

ORANGE = (255, 140, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
DARKBLUE = (0, 0, 139)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
DARKGREEN = (0, 98, 7)
LIMEGREEN = (50, 205, 50)
DARKGREY = (70, 70, 70)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
LIGHTBLUE = (173, 216, 230)
WOODY = (139,69,19)

LIST_OF_ALL_COLOR_NAMES = [ ORANGE, RED, DARKBLUE, WHITE, BLACK, YELLOW, GREEN, DARKGREEN, LIMEGREEN,
                            DARKGREY, BLUE, LIGHTBLUE ]

###############################################################
# Konstanten
###############################################################

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1200
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
PANEL_SIZE = 160
SQUARE_SIZE = 80
#SIDEPANEL = pygame.Rect(pxl(13), pxl(0), pxl(2), pxl(10))
background = pygame.Rect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

###############################################################
# Measurement -> Maßeinheit und Bildschirmmaße
###############################################################

def pxl (number_of_squares):
    "number of squares -> number of pixels"
    return SQUARE_SIZE * number_of_squares

###############################################################
# Variablen
###############################################################

level = 0
a = 1085
b = 80
gameDrawn = False
counter = 15
timerRect = pygame.Rect(pxl(13), pxl(0), pxl(1), pxl(1))
counterRect = pygame.Rect(pxl(14), pxl(0), pxl(3), pxl(1))


###############################################################
# Classes -> Klassen
###############################################################

class Wall(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], pxl(1), pxl(1))

class End(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], pxl(1), pxl(1))
        
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], pxl(1), pxl(1))

    #def move(dx, dy):
        # Bewegung für x und y. Kollision wird überprüft
        #if dx != 0:
            #wallCollisionDetection((dx, 0))
        #if dy != 0:
            #wallCollisionDetection(0, dy)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        walls = drawLevel(level)
        # Den Spieler bewegen
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0:  
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0:
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0:  
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0:
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
        

    

    #def endCollisionDetection(self, dx, dy):

###############################################################
# Listen
###############################################################



move_list = []

max_move_list = [17]

levels =[[  "WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
            "W          EW",
            "W         WWW",
            "W   WWWW    W",
            "W   W       W",
            "WWWWW  WWWW W",
            "W   W     W W",
            "W   W     W W",
            "WP          W",
            "WWWWWWWWWWWWW",
        ]]

curr_moves = max_move_list[level]

###############################################################
# Methoden
###############################################################

def movePlayer(move_list):
    for i in move_list:
        if i == 1:
            player.move(pxl(0), pxl(-1))
        elif i == 2:
            player.move(pxl(0), pxl(1))
        elif i == 3:
            player.move(pxl(1), pxl(0))
        elif i == 4:
            player.move(pxl(-1), pxl(0))

def drawGrid():
    for x in range(0, SCREEN_WIDTH - PANEL_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE):
        for y in range(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SQUARE_SIZE):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, rect, 1)

def drawRect():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (pygame.Rect(pxl(13), pxl(0), pxl(2), pxl(10))))

def drawStartMessage():

    startText11 = "Das Spiel funktioniert so:"
    startText22 = "Sobald es startet, haben sie 15 Sekunden Zeit um ihre Züge einzugeben."
    startText33 = "Das Ziel ist es den Spieler (blaues Rechteck) ins Ziel (rotes Rechteck) zu bekommen."
    startText44 = "Dazu haben sie neben den 15 Sekunden eine gewisse Anzahl an Zügen."
    startText55 = "Drücken sie eine Taste zum Starten"
    startText1 = font.render(startText11, True, BLACK)
    startText2 = font.render(startText22, True, BLACK)
    startText3 = font.render(startText33, True, BLACK)
    startText4 = font.render(startText44, True, BLACK)
    startText5 = font.render(startText55, True, BLACK)
    startText1_rect = startText1.get_rect(center=(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 160))
    startText2_rect = startText2.get_rect(center=(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 240))
    startText3_rect = startText3.get_rect(center=(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 320))
    startText4_rect = startText4.get_rect(center=(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 400))
    startText5_rect = startText5.get_rect(center=(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 640))

    screen.blit(startText1, startText1_rect)
    screen.blit(startText2, startText2_rect)
    screen.blit(startText3, startText3_rect)
    screen.blit(startText4, startText4_rect)
    screen.blit(startText5, startText5_rect)

def drawLevel(level):
    global gameDrawn
    x = y = 0

    

    walls = []

    ends = []

    players = []
    if gameDrawn == False:
        screen.fill(WOODY)
        drawGrid()
        drawRect()
        for row in levels[level]:
            for col in row:
                if col == "W":
                    wall = Wall((x, y))
                    walls.append(wall)
                if col == "E":
                    end = End((x, y))
                    ends.append(end)
                if col == "P":
                    player = Player((x,y))
                    players.append(player)
                x += 80
            y += 80
            x = 0
        for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, wall.rect)
        for end in ends:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, end.rect)
        for player in players:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, player.rect)
    gameDrawn = True
    #elif gameDrawn == True:
        #for event in pygame.event.get():
            #if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT: 
                #drawTimer(counter)
                #counter -= 1  
    return players, walls, ends

#def drawPlayerPath():

#def getPlayerPath():
#    players, _, _ = drawLevel(level)
#    player_x, player_y = players[0]
#    for i in move_list:
#        if i == 1:
#            player_y += -1
#        elif i == 2:
#            player_y += 1
#        elif i == 3:
#            player_x += -1
#        elif i == 4:
#            player_x += -1
#        players.append((player_x, player_y))



def calcCounter():
    global curr_moves
    curr_moves += 1
    return curr_moves

def drawCounter(curr_moves):
    global screen
    text_currMoves = font.render(str(curr_moves) + "/" + str(max_move_list[level]), True, BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, counterRect)
    screen.blit(text_currMoves, (1130,40))
    if curr_moves == 0:
        state = "running"
        init_state = True

def writeMoves():
    a = 1085
    b = 80
    for i in range(len(move_list)):
        if move_list[i] == 1:
            screen.blit(text_up, (a, b))
        elif move_list[i] == 2:
            screen.blit(text_down, (a, b))            
        elif move_list[i] == 3:
            screen.blit(text_right, (a, b))            
        elif move_list[i] == 4:
            screen.blit(text_left, (a, b))
        b += 40            

def wallCollisionDetection(player, wall, dx, dy):
    walls = drawLevel(level)
    players = drawLevel(level)
    for wall in walls:
        if player.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
            if dx > 0:  
                player.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            if dx < 0:  
                player.rect.left = wall.rect.right
            if dy > 0:  
                player.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            if dy < 0:  
                player.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom





pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 30)


###############################################################
# Game-States
###############################################################

def init_state_start():
    pass

def main_loop_state_start():
    global state, init_state
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            print("Spiel wird beendet!")
            
            # User-Input wird erfasst

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            state = "config"
            init_state = True


        # draw screen -> Startbildschirm wird "gemalt"
    screen.fill(LIGHTBLUE)
    drawStartMessage()

def init_state_config():
    pass

def main_loop_state_config():
    global level, end_rect, curr_moves, max_moves, i, j, counter
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1500)
    drawLevel(level)
    players, walls, ends = drawLevel(level)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            counter -= 1  
            counterT = font.render(str(counter), True, BLACK)
            screen.blit(counterT, (1070, 40))           
        if event.type == QUIT or event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            print("Spiel wird beendet!")
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:               
                    move_list.append(1)                    
                    curr_moves -= 1
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    move_list.append(2)                   
                    curr_moves -= 1
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    move_list.append(3)                    
                    curr_moves -= 1
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                    move_list.append(4)
                    curr_moves -= 1
            if counter == 0:
                state = "running"
                init_state = True 
        drawCounter(curr_moves)
        
        
    writeMoves()
    pygame.display.flip()

def init_state_running():
    pass

def main_loop_state_running():
    global level
    players, _, _ = drawLevel(level)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            print("Spiel wird beendet!")
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            print(move_list)
        for player in players:
            movePlayer(move_list)

###############################################################
# Measurement -> Maßeinheit und Bildschirmmaße
###############################################################

def pxl (number_of_squares):
    "number of squares -> number of pixels"
    return SQUARE_SIZE * number_of_squares

###############################################################
# Font and Texts
###############################################################


font = pygame.font.SysFont("Consolas", 20)
moveFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)  # Schrift für Züge
startFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)   # Schrift für den Startbildschirm
timerFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)   # Schrift für den Timer
text_up = font.render("OBEN", True, BLACK)
text_down = font.render("UNTEN", True, BLACK)
text_right = font.render("RECHTS", True, BLACK)
text_left = font.render("LINKS", True, BLACK)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))  # Fensterbreite und länge in pixeln, nur der Zeichenbereich


###############################################################
# Generelles Setup
###############################################################

  # Schnelligkeit des Spiels festlegen, damit es überall gleich schnell läuft
state = "start"
init_state = True

###############################################################
# Screen-Settings
###############################################################


pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame")

###############################################################
# Main-Game-Loop
###############################################################



running = True
while running:
    if state == "start":
        if init_state:
            init_state_start()
            init_state = False
        else:    
            main_loop_state_start()
    elif state == "config":
        if init_state:
            init_state_config()
            init_state = False
        else:   
            main_loop_state_config()
            if counter == 0:
                state = "running"
                init_state = True
            if curr_moves == 0:
                state = "running"
                init_state = True
    elif state == "running":
        if init_state:
            init_state_running()
            init_state = False
        else:
            main_loop_state_running()
            
            
    
       # update window
    clock.tick(60)          # set refresh rate
    pygame.display.flip()

###############################################################
```

It would be really amazing if you could help me and explain the error to me, since I have to do that stuff for university. Thank you really much :D

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the count down event on pygame which is worked perfectly. it seems your codes are messed. following is the working code for count down. place the code  on on your required function

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Count Down")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 128))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

_counter, text = 10, '10'.rjust(3)
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Consolas', 30)

run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.USEREVENT: 
            _counter -= 1
            text = str(_counter).rjust(3) if _counter > 0 else 'boom!'
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            run = False

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (32, 48))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: I know that code. Its from the internet. But its still about where to place it

Comment: at what time / position you want to place that code?